# Any suggestions on how to optimize this string -> double parser further, in F#?

Tags: parsing, optimization, f#

Part of testing, I have to load massive CSV files (200+mb each) and I'm trying to cut down the load time since this is adding up.

As the CSV files are all floating point numbers, I tried to see if I could speed that up.
One important point: I do NOT need precision beyond 5 digits after the comma. The code I post here parses it anyways to give a fair comparison to .NET's parser, but any shortcut that preserves that precision is good.

The code I came up with:

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =

    let r = Random()

    let numbers =
        seq {
            for _ in 0 .. 10000000 do
                let n = (1000. * r.NextDouble()) - 500.
                yield (n, sprintf "%.8f" n)
        }
        |> Seq.toList


    let parseString (number: string) : double =
        let len = number.Length
        let rec parse (index: int) (nSign: double) (signMultiplier: double) (nAccumulator: int64) : float =
            if index < len then
                match number.[index] with
                | x when x >= '0' && x <= '9' -> parse (index + 1) (signMultiplier * nSign) signMultiplier (nAccumulator * 10L + int64 x - int64 '0')
                | x when x = '.'              -> parse (index + 1) nSign 0.1 nAccumulator
                | x when x = '-'              -> parse (index + 1) -nSign signMultiplier nAccumulator
                | _                           -> parse (index + 1) nSign signMultiplier nAccumulator
            else
                double nAccumulator * nSign

        parse 0 +1. 1. 0L



    let benchmark name (func: string -> double) =
        let allowedError = 0.00001
        printf "checking %s - " name
        let sw = Stopwatch()
        sw.Start()
        numbers
        |> List.iter (fun (num, str) ->
            let parsed = func str
            let delta = num - parsed
            if abs delta > allowedError then
                failwithf "(%f, %s) not matching %f" num str parsed
        )
        sw.Stop()
        printfn "%i ms" sw.ElapsedMilliseconds


    benchmark ".net parser" (fun x -> double x)
    benchmark "parser1" (fun x -> parseString x)

    0
```

Is there anything obvious I missed to speed this up?

Additionally, there is something I do not understand: I tried to make the test numbers an array instead of a list and suddenly the processing took longer, while I'd expect the opposite. If anyone has some insights as to why it is happening, I'd be happy to know. You can just change the toList to toArray and replace the List with Array in the benchmark loop to test this.

---

Edit:

to load the data, here is the code I use:

```
// load a csv file
let loadCSV (stream: Stream) =
    seq {
        use s = new StreamReader (stream)
        while not s.EndOfStream do
            yield s.ReadLine ()
    }
    |> Seq.map (fun line -> line.Split(",") |> Array.toList)
    |> Seq.toList
```

Comment: Have you thought of using FParsec or even CsvHelper instead of rolling your own parser? Files are read as streams, not individual strings. The very act of reading a line creates a new temporary string that needs to be GC'd.  Both FParsec and CsvHelper read from an input stream so they avoid allocating big temporary strings. The test you posted doesn't measure that at all, so it's not really useful.

Comment: BTW a single test run isn't enough to run an accurate benchmark. The timing can be affected by warmup and other running applications. Even repeating the same operation for eg 1000 times may give inaccurate results due to warmup and transient issues. Use  BenchmarkDotNet instead and let it run the test (using an actual file) long enough to collect stable, statistically significant results. BDN collects memory allocations and GC information as well, which shows you how efficient your algorithm really is.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I didn't think of the GC for every string, but that's a very good point; I think I had tunnel vision on one problem and didn't consider the rest! I will check these libraries, thanks

Comment: In parsing, memory allocations and GCs are the biggest performance issue. That, and caching everything vs working on a stream. If you use eg `File.ReadAllLines` you have to wait for all lines to be read before processing them (never mind allocating a 200MB array, and another 200MB in reallocated temporary buffers). With `ReadLine` you can process lines as they become available, without keeping anything more in memory

Comment: I edited the question and put the loading code; so, you can see that I'm building a long list of lists; I will check how csvhelper performs

Comment: You could even try using the built-in [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netcore-3.1) which should work perfectly fine in f# despite the namespace.  It should handle escaping of `,` characters correctly, which `line.Split(",")` does not.

Comment: @Thomas, If using CsvHelper isn't enough then multi-core machines give a speedup if you open each CSV in a separate stream and process them asynchronously.  You can even break up large CSVs, process them on separate threads, and then merge the results.

Comment: @rfreytag, CsvHelper gave me a 2x speed increase